# ERROR - Runtime.HandlerNotFound: Handler 'lambda_handler' missing on module 'lambda_function'

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

My apologies for basic question. I am completely new to AWS as well as Python. I am trying to do sample code but facing a error. I'm trying to read some data from a dynamodb table, but facing error like this in AWS Cloudwatch logs:

> "Runtime.HandlerNotFound: Handler 'lambda_handler' missing on module 'lambda_function'".

And Postman is throwing error as

> "message": "Internal server error"

The code is:

```
    import boto3

    class userProfile:

        def __init__(self):
            dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
            self.table = dynamodb.Table('user_data')

        def Create_table():
            pass

        def Read_table(self, event):
            response = self.table.get_item(
                Key = {
                    'user_name' : event['user_name']
                }
            )
            if 'Item' in response:
                return response['Item']

            else:
                return {
                    'statusCode':'404',
                    'body' : 'User Name ' + 'id ' + 'not found'
                }

        def Update_tabel():
            pass


    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        if event:
            user_Object = userProfile()
            if event["tasktype"] == "read":
                read_result = user_Object.Read_table(event['data'])
                return read_result
        else:
            return {
                'statusCode': '404',
                'body': 'Not found'
            }
```

Comment: Make sure when you are selecting the lambda function you define it as <file_name>.lambda_handler

Comment: Also: not related to your question but you may want to initiate your boto resources outside of that class. Take a look at Lambda's execution environment reuse: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html